# mvc dropdownlist not showing data value

Tags: model-view-controller, drop-down-menu

I'm having an issue displaying data from the database into drop-downlist.

controller

```
TowinsEntities db = new TowinsEntities();  

    public ActionResult TMakes()
    {
        //T_Make make_db = new Models.T_Make();
        ViewBag.carMaker = new SelectList(db.T_Make, "Make");
        return View();
    }
```

view

```
 @Html.DropDownList("carMaker", "Select Make")
```

model

```
public partial class T_Make
{
    public string Make { get; set; }
}
```

The output of a view is:

[image: dropdownlist-error<code>enter code here</code>]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to overload your DropDownList with the string field names you want for value/display.  You're only passing the model and selected value.  I guess you'd use Make for both value and display (though, most people would use an ID for a value)

```
ViewBag.carMaker = new SelectList(db.T_Make, "Make","Make");
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.selectlist.-ctor?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_SelectList__ctor_System_Collections_IEnumerable_System_String_System_String_

Comment: Thanks! it did work. Yes, the table does not contain id attribute, so was creating a function to add ID, but this is a really simple fix.

Comment: No problem, I'm happy that worked out for you.  If you get a chance can you please mark this as the answer / upvote if you want so it's not listed as "unanswered"?